# Restrict content elements with IP in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

My requirement is to restrict a content element with IP of a specific country (Eg: Austria). That means people visiting the website from Austrian IPs should be visible the content element and for all other users, it should be hidden. I am using geoip solution to check the country. I wrote a user function to implement this feature. I wrote a small extension and set hidden flag 1 and 0 based on countries. But due to TYPO3 caching, I want to clear the cache everytime to reflect the changes in frontend. I included the extension as USER_INT, and extension is non-cachable. But unfortunately not working. Functionality working, but due to caching changes not reflect in realtime.

```
$uid = 175; // uid of the content element needs to be hidden         
$geoplugin = new \geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
$countryCode = $geoplugin->countryCode;
if( $countryCode == 'AT' ){
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery('tt_content', 'uid IN ('.$uid.')', array('hidden' => 0));
}else{
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery('tt_content', 'uid IN ('.$uid.')', array('hidden' => 1));
}
```

Is there any method available in TYPO3 to restrict content element for specific IP / Countries? or can you guys suggest a solution to fix this please?

Comment: My approach would be to create my own uncached plugin. In this plugin, the user can choose a content element to show, and the regions where the content should be visible/invisible. The plugin then just renders the content element, or nothing, depending on the remote users IP.

Comment: Could you imagin to implement such filtered content via ajax? Then you avoid hassle with caching mechanism

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Jost is much less dirty than hiding the element in the database depending on the visitors country. By your way the database probably changed on every user visit.
Just create a micro extension.

Comment: ok will try to implement that. Can you please tell me a good approach to implement this functionality? My plugin is non cachable, but still typo3 cache affect on the functionality.

Comment: You can create a small extension with the extension builder having a small frontend plugin. Add a flexform to the plugin in which you can choose a tt_content element if it matches the desired country. Add more settings for the countries or other conditions.

Comment: And set the plugin / ControllerAction inside the ext_localconf to non-cacheable.

Comment: This ext_localconf setting is strict cached... clear the install tool cache or reinstall your extension.
Instead of a extension you could also use a Typoscript Object COA_INT with a CONTENT object inside it and then select the desired content from the DB using Typoscript. But then you need a field "country" inside the tt_content table to select the proper items.